# Is there a way to see if a specific Add-In is installed?

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, office365-apps, outlook-web-app

Is there a way (API or other?) to find out if an add-in is installed?

I'm looking at augmenting the Exchange install to insert my own button to tell my user if an Outlook add-in is installed or not?

Is there an API for finding out?

Answer (score 0):

The Office Object Model has a COMAddins collection accessible from the Outlook.Application object that you can use to iterate through all registered add-ins.  Any add-in that is loaded will have COMAddin.Connect set to True (which you can set to False to unload the add-in).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff870066.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The trick to doing this in Exchange and OWA (not desktop Outlook) is to use JS to manually open the Add-Ins pane and try to click your add-in. Not perfect, I realize, but it does satisfy the original requirement even though there is no direct API support.

Edit the file named, microsoft.owa.mail.compose.js and find a good place to enter something similar to the following.

```html
var workDocument = (this.bh.bz) ? $(this.bh.bz.document) : window.document;
var yourAddIn = $(workDocument).find('iframe[title="Your_Add-In_Name"]');
if (yourAddIn.length > 0) {
 yourAddIn[0].contentWindow.postMessage({ id: 'Look_for_your_id_using_DevTools_F12_and_Find_the_id', message: 'send'}, '*');
 return;
} else {
 // Click Add-in button, click the add-in name in the add-ins list
 var addInsButton = $(workDocument).find("button[title='Add-ins']");
 if (addInsButton.length <= 0) {
  return;
 }
 addInsButton[0].click();
                               
}
```